# selenium python chrome headless mode unsupported

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have just started using `selenium python` to parse through a single page app for images and other data. It requires a login. When not in `headless` mode; my code works; I can make form submissions and proceed on with other things. But as soon as I enable headless mode; it loads the page (Debugging through taking screenshots via `driver.save_screenshot()`) and it gets stuck on submission.

```py
....
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        "./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("")
# driver.save_screenshot() gives the expected result. The form is visible
    try:
        password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'input')))
        password_field.clear()
        password_field.send_keys(ott_key)
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", submit_button)
        # submit_button.click() # tried with submit() as well
        driver.save_screenshot("test.png")
# it gets stuck after submitting but only when it is in headless mode. Otherwise it carries on.
....
```

Now I don't know how to even begin debugging; as you can see, I have tried changing user agents; maximizing window; etc.
Would really appreciate a suggestion.
**EDIT**
I was finally able to debug the issue, in headless mode it is unsupported by the SPA. So to mitigate that I used

```py
  chrome_options.add_argument(
        f"user-agent={'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'}")
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: At what line is it stuck?
You can add print statements between lines to see where you end up
The problem might be different depending if the waits are hanging or the submit itself

Comment: you have driver.get("") ?!

Comment: @PDHide no no thats cause I removed the link before posting it here.

Comment: try adding --disable-gpu also to arguments

Comment: @OranShuster I have some comments; Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @PDHide Have already tried that I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I found the issue and it was that the website was blocking headless browsers specifically. So I had to use `xvfb` (fake display) and `pyvirtualdisplay` to get it working.